# WSO2 Data Service, Enterprise Integrator and Data Mapper mediator

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, dataservice, wso2-esb

I have created a Data Service (DS) and expose the data as a REST resource. and  I could successfully retrieve data via CURL command given below.

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8280/services/TestDataService.HTTPEndpoint/Member/0
```

The REST API resource template is **Member/{MemberID}** - **DS Endpoint**

The response is,

```
{"Members":{"Email":"example@test.com","FirstName":"Mad","MembershipCategory":"Gold","InsuranceType":"Health","LastName":"Tim"}}
```

---

Then I wanted to convert this JSON response to a CSV using WSO2 EI's **Data Mapper mediator**. *I know there are alternative ways to achieve this usecase via other mediators or WSO2 API manager.*

I created another API resource in WSO2 EI which has the template

**/convertDetails/Member/{MemberID}** - **EI Endpoint**

Anyhow, with following configurations, I could not get the correct response when I call the REST API resource from a REST client.

Following is my mediation flow,

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/convertDetails" name="MemberDetailsConversion" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/Member/{MemberID}">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request Log" level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/TestDataService.HTTPEndpoint/Member/{uri.var.MemberID}"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/MemberDetailsMapping.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/MemberDetailsMapping_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/MemberDetailsMapping_outputSchema.json" outputType="CSV"/>
            <log description="Response Log" level="full"/>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

But still when I invoke the EI REST resource endpoint, http://localhost:8280/convertDetails/Member/0, it give me an ERROR.I have extracted the first few lines of the stack below.

```
[2018-11-01 10:30:30,817] [EI-Core] ERROR - DBInOutMessageReceiver Error in in-out message receiver
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:MemberID
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: TestDataService
Location: /Users/mad/Documents/wso2ei-6.3.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1541088489969TestDataServiceProjectCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/TestDataService_1.0.0/TestDataService-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getmember_memberid
Current Params: {}
```

I'm assuming that I have missed something along the configuration. Would appreciate your help regarding this.

Comment: have you checked the value of the uri.var.MemberID property? Maybe log it before sending the request to your DataService to see if it gets properly extracted. Also you can turn on wirelogging to see what exactly is being sent to the DataService.